# How to add CSS properties to HTML tags in Servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm creating a simple web application in which,

- The JSP file takes `username` as an input from the user.
- a Servlet class which captures this `username` and says "Hello" followed by the `username`.

> My question is, How to add `color` property to the below Greeting message in
>   Servlet class ?

```
    out.println("<h2>");
    out.println("Hello "+capturedInput);
    out.println("</h2>");
```

**Source Code:**

JSP file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JSP PAGE</h1>

    <form method = "post" action="HelloMessageServlet">
        Name: <input type="text" name="username"><br> <input
            type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet Class

```
public class HelloMessageServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String capturedInput = request.getParameter("username");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h2>");
    out.println("Hello "+capturedInput);
    out.println("</h2>");

    out.println("<p>");
    out.println("posted from Servlet Class");
    out.println("</p>");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
out.println("<h2 style='color:red'>");
out.println("Hello "+capturedInput);
out.println("</h2>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Like how you insert styling in the HTML tags.

```html
<h2 style='color:blue'>Hello</h2>
```

The same applies here, we should enclose style attribute in the HTML tags: 

`out.println("<h2 style='color:blue'>");`